# Debug configuration to start with specific Python file. -VSCode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, web2py

I am currently playing with a Web2Py application. It is lovely to write python in VSCode. I am looking for a way to minimize the steps to start debugging this application. Currently, I navigate to the File panel and then to the web2py.py file. I open that up and begin debugging.

I am sure there are some creative ways to script my way out of this, or just put some property settings somewhere.

Please share some insights!

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a launch configuration in *launch.json* to run the application, like this:

```json
        {
            "name": "Python: My web2py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "program": "<folder to web2py sourcecode>/web2py/web2py.py",
            "args": ["-p 8000", "--password=admin", "--nogui"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "<folder to web2py sourcecode>/web2py/",
        }
```

If you are using a version control software, like git, you will need to add a softlink between your source and the web2py application folder:

```sh
ln -s /<folder>/git/myproject/src /<folder>/web2py/applications/myproject
```

Now you can open the project on VSCode and run debug.

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching for Keyboard shortcuts and found this reference:
[VS Code Twiter post (shortcut pdfs)](https://twitter.com/code/status/910620246477639680)
So I used Ctrl+F to Find 'Quick Open' (Ctrl+P)

I can type Web2Py [It autocompletes!]

Enter

F5

Ctrl+W

Bam! I wonder still if there is a way that, while in this project, I can just hit F5